# How to get average for each date by considering current date and previous all date data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have below dataframe and I want to calcultae cumulative average for each date by considering current date and previous all date data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Items':['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item1', 'Item2', 'Item1', 'Item2', 'Item1', 'Item2', 'Item1', 'Item2', 'Item1'],
         'Variable': ['V1', 'V2', 'V1', 'V2', 'V1', 'V2', 'V1', 'V2', 'V1', 'V2', 'V1'],
         'Date': ['2020-12-16', '2020-12-16', '2020-12-16', '2020-12-16', '2020-12-17', '2020-12-17', '2020-12-17', '2020-12-17', '2020-12-18', '2020-12-18', '2020-12-18'],
         'Value': [5, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]})

df = df.sort_values(['Date'], ascending=[True])
```

but below script does not help:

```
df.groupby(['Items', 'Variable', 'Date'])['Value'].expanding().mean().reset_index(name='Value')
```

I need result like below:
[image]

In MS excel we can find average for latest date -2018 by selecting all previous rows like below:

[image]

like above I want to calculate for all dates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Items', 'Date', 'Variable'], ascending=[True, True, True])

x = df.reset_index().groupby(['Items', 'Variable'])['Value']
index = x.cumcount()+1
df['Value'] = x.cumsum()/(index.values)

df1 = df[np.where(df[['Items', 'Variable', 'Date']].duplicated(keep='last'), False, True)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

**df1:**

```
    Items   Variable    Date    Value
0   Item1   V1       2020-12-16 5.000000
1   Item1   V1       2020-12-17 3.000000
2   Item1   V1       2020-12-18 2.333333
3   Item2   V2       2020-12-16 1.500000
4   Item2   V2       2020-12-17 1.500000
5   Item2   V2       2020-12-18 1.400000
```

**Edit:**

Instead of `df[np.where(df[['Items', 'Variable', 'Date']].duplicated(keep='last'), False, True)].reset_index(drop=True)`

use `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Items', 'Variable', 'Date'], keep='last').reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: I ain't getting the exact result because of `(x.index+1)`

Comment: thanks,, but  Item2 ,V2, 2020-12-16 & 2020-12-17 date values are wrong, it should be 1.5 then Item2 ,V2, 2020-12-18 should be 1.4

Comment: @SPy: as I told it was due to index only. I fixed it. For each group the index will always start form 1. So that I can divide but I didn't do that step for these two different group. Check now. Btw merry christmas in advance buddy :)

Comment: Neat! You probably don't need the second `reset_index` here `x = df.reset_index()...`?

Comment: I forgot to remove that. Thanks for poitning this out.

Comment: @Pygirl thanks a lot. this is working. Merry Christmas and happy new year in advance. Thanks :)

Comment: @Pygirl Nice idea using `cumsum` and `cumcount` +1..I think you can use `drop_duplicates` in place of `np.where` + `duplicated` and also no need to specify the `ascending` parameter its default value is `True`.

Comment: @Pygirl If you like i can edit the answer :)

Comment: I updated my asnwer. I was thinking to use drop_duplicate but was not able to write(syntax) your comment gave me clear vision how to use it `np.where + duplicated` --> `drop_duplicate`. Thanks @ShubhamSharma

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see from you excel sheet, this is what you want to do:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Variable','Date'], ascending=[True,True])
df['cummean'] = df.groupby(['Variable'])['Value'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(6,1).mean())
```

which return

```
    Items Variable        Date  Value   cummean
0   Item1       V1  2020-12-16      5  5.000000
2   Item1       V1  2020-12-16      1  3.000000
4   Item1       V1  2020-12-17      1  2.333333
6   Item1       V1  2020-12-17      1  2.000000
8   Item1       V1  2020-12-18      1  1.800000
10  Item1       V1  2020-12-18      1  1.666667
1   Item2       V2  2020-12-16      5  5.000000
3   Item2       V2  2020-12-16      1  3.000000
5   Item2       V2  2020-12-17      1  2.333333
7   Item2       V2  2020-12-17      2  2.250000
9   Item2       V2  2020-12-18      1  2.000000
```

Comment: but its giving duplicates